# "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

This is an error that appeard a few years ago.  I have not experienced this until the past two weeks with all my Visual Studio installations.  I've tried all the solutions from past posts that I found.  None worked.  I suspect the error is with the DNN Templates Version 9.  Can you confirm?

> The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be loaded from the assembly … packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll.  Could not load file or assembly … packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: According to error log, you should check if the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll exists in the folder "..\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools", if not, you should re-install that package.

Comment: I had to manually change the version # both in the targets file "~\BuildScripts\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" and in the csproj file:

    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>

Answer (score 3):

The call is to the Buildscripts folder and the DLL is in the packages folder.

Copy the DLL from `\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools` and paste the DLL into the BuildScripts folder. Make sure to close/reopen the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall the package from NuGet into your project since the error message states that it is missing.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuildTasks

Comment: Thank you.  Once NuGet was selected with the project open the error message appears indicating an error with MSBuild accompanied by a restore button.  Selecting restore appears to solve the issue.  Important that the restore be done just after project is created.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually change the version # both in the targets file "~\BuildScripts\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" and in the csproj file:

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.5.0.235\tools</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

Answer (score 0):

We found that sometimes you have to change

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

in the project file, as it overrides the nuget package settings